# Definition of a stalk why must we be careful about the equivalence realtion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

We define a stalk as follows. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$ and let $p$ be a point in $X$.

The stalk $\mathcal{F}_p:\{(U,s)\mid p\in U \subset X \text{ an open set and } s\in \mathcal{F} \}/\sim$. Where $(U,s)\sim (U',s')$ if $s\mid_V=s'\mid_V$ for some $V\subset U\cap U'$ open.

Seemingly we cannot always replace $V$ with $U\cap U'$ as then this would not be an equivalence relation, but I cannot come up with an example on how this fails to be an equivalence relation.

Comment: Do you mean $s\in\mathcal{F}(U)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens if we have a $U''$ properly contained in $U\cap U'$. We could have pairs $(U,s)$, $(U', s')$, and $(U'', s'')$ such that $s$ agrees with $s''$ on $U\cap U''=U''$ and $s'$ agrees with $s''$ on $U'\cap U''=U''$, but $s$ and $s'$ don't agree on the larger set $U\cap U'$. So transitivity could fail in general if we don't "cut down" appropriately.

Comment: Ah this is clear now thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\{a,b,p\}$ with the discrete topology, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the constant sheaf with value $\Bbb Z$. Consider the following global sections, both of which assign $0$ to $p$:

- $\alpha$, which assigns $1$ to $a$ and $0$ to $b$,
- $\beta$, which assigns $0$ to $a$ and $1$ to $b$.

Using the relation of "agreeing where defined", these are both equivalent to the local section defined on $\{p\}$ which assigns $0$ to $p$, but they're not equivalent to each other. So the relation is not transitive.

Comment: I thought the $\mathcal{F}$ you have described is not a sheaf and only a presheaf

Comment: No, it's definitely a sheaf. Are you familiar with the [constant sheaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_sheaf)?

Comment: Hmm, I think I had the idea of a constant sheaf wrong. I thought the constant sheaf was $A^p_X$ where $A$ is an ableian group, $X$ a topological space: for every $U\subset X$ open we define $A^p_X(U)=A$ and the restriction maps are the identity maps. 

To see this is not a sheaf: make $U,V$ disjoint in $X$. If this is a sheaf we can define a section locally on $U$ and $V$ and glue it to a global section. But locally we can choose our section to take value $a$ on U$ and $b$ on $V$, But then this is not a constant section

Have I miss understood something?

Comment: Well, that's certainly a presheaf, and if you sheafify it, you get the constant sheaf. The constant sheaf with value $A$ has all stalks equal to $A$, and since our space is discrete, the stalks specify the sheaf. You may wish to go read more about the constant sheaf, like at the link in my last comment.